# How can I plot online data coming from two different sources in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, streaming, plotly

I am trying to plot online data coming from two different sources in this way:

In each iteration:

1] first source: add incoming data to the graph.

2] second source: delete previous data and keep only the incoming ones in the graph.

I gave a try to [plotly](https://plot.ly/streaming/) but the problem is that you can't delete data once it have been plotted (I need this for the incoming data from the second source).

### UPDATE:

Inspired from @WakkaDojo answer here is the final code where I used [malplotlib.animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

fig = plt.figure()#figsize=(7,4), dpi=100

ylim(0,20)
xlim(0,20)

def data_gen():
    centers = [[15, 15],[5, 5]]
    for i in range(1000):
        X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=2, centers=centers, cluster_std=1.0,center_box=(-1, 1))
        print i
        yield float(X[0][0]), float(X[0][1]), float(X[1][0]), float(X[1][1])


updated_source_1, = plot([], [], linestyle='none', marker='o', color='g')
updated_source_2, = plot([], [], linestyle='none', marker='o', color='r')

ax = gca()

source_1_xdata, source_1_ydata = [], []
source_2_xdata, source_2_ydata = [0], [0]


def run(data):
    x0,y0,x1,y1 = data

    # remove previous plotted data

    source_2_xdata.remove(xdata1[len(xdata1)-1])
    source_2_ydata.remove(ydata1[len(ydata1)-1])

    # append new data

    source_1_xdata.append(x0)
    source_1_ydata.append(y0)
    source_2_xdata.append(x1)
    source_2_ydata.append(y1)
    updated_source_1.set_data(source_1_ydata, source_1_xdata)
    updated_source_2.set_data(source_2_ydata, source_2_xdata)
    return updated_source_1, updated_source_2,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to "delete" data already plotted would be to just **replot** the data. Think of storing your data in lists, where you can easily add or remove data, and then just replot as updates come in.

A simple way to keep the latest N points in a list is

```
def add_data (new_data, old_data, n): # keep n points
    return (old_data + new_data)[-n:]
```